# Add Sum Of Two Input Values Automatically without clicking a single button

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have tried all codes avaliable but nothing worked.
Here is the Code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<script>
var text1 = document.getElementById("inhouse");
var text2 = document.getElementById("sahodaya");

function showsum() {
   var first_number = parseFloat(text1.value);
   if (isNaN(first_number)) first_number = 0;
   var second_number = parseFloat(text2.value);
   if (isNaN(second_number)) second_number = 0;
   var result = first_number + second_number;
   document.getElementById("total").value = result;
}
</script>
    <title>Sahodaya 25 Report - Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "container my-3">
        <form method="POST">
<fieldset disabled>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="disabledTextInput" class="form-label">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']?>" name = "name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']?>">
      
      
      <label for="disabledTextInput2" class="form-label my-2">Email</label>
      <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput2" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']?>" name = "email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']?>">
      
      </fieldset>
      <label for="inhouse" class="form-label">Inhouse Training Done In Hours</label>
      <input type="number" id="inhouse" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Here" name = "inhouse" required oninput="showsum()"><br>
      
      <label for="sahodaya" class="form-label">Sahodaya Training Done In Hours</label>
      <input type="number" id="sahodaya" class="form-control" placeholder="JSSC + PSCC (Both)" name = "sahodaya" oninput="showsum()" required><br>
      
      <label for="total" class="form-label">Total Hours Done</label>
      <input type="number" id="total" class="form-control" name = "total" value="0"><br>
      
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

But this Code is Not Wokring I tried all Solutions Available on Stack Overflow that I seen till now but nothing helped much So i m posting this if somebody can help.

I want to add the value in inhouse and sahodaya and show it in total input field.

But when I m running this it's not wokring. How can i fix this Error.

Comment: Can Anyone Help Plz

Comment: You have to make a function call `add_number()` and i think you have to set defults values to the input could you explain more about your problem?

Comment: _"Can Anyone Help Plz "_ - can you first of all show some _patience_, instead of getting pushy after not even five minutes?

Comment: You are not calling `add_number` _anywhere_, so how would this be supposed to work then? Add an `input` or `change` handler to the input fields, that calls this function ...

Comment: @CBroe oninput="showsum()" I m using this

Comment: @CBroe This is my First Question on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code. It should fix the issue.

**Full working code snippet:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script>
    function add_number() {
      var first_number = parseFloat(document.getElementById("inhouse").value);
      if (isNaN(first_number)) first_number = 0;
      var second_number = parseFloat(document.getElementById("sahodaya").value);
      if (isNaN(second_number)) second_number = 0;
      var result = first_number + second_number;
      document.getElementById("total").value = result;
    }
  </script>
  <title>Sahodaya 25 Report - Form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container my-3">
    <form method="POST">
      <fieldset disabled>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="disabledTextInput" class="form-label">Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']?>" name="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']?>">


          <label for="disabledTextInput2" class="form-label my-2">Email</label>
          <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput2" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']?>" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']?>">

      </fieldset>
      <label for="inhouse" class="form-label">Inhouse Training Done In Hours</label>
      <input type="number" id="inhouse" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Here" name="inhouse" required onkeyup="add_number()"><br>

      <label for="sahodaya" class="form-label">Sahodaya Training Done In Hours</label>
      <input type="number" id="sahodaya" class="form-control" placeholder="JSSC + PSCC (Both)" name="sahodaya" onkeyup="add_number()" required><br>

      <label for="total" class="form-label">Total Hours Done</label>
      <input type="number" id="total" class="form-control" name="total" value="0"><br>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the document.getElementById call inside the function or should move the script block below your form.

Your document will be rendered line by line by the browser. Since you've your script tag before the form element. the elements were not available when you call the `document.getElementById("inhouse")` so the var `first_number` gets undefined and when the form is rendered the element will be available. But still your var is undefined. That's why your code is not getting executed.

I've also refactored your function to arrow function and removed few unnecessary methods.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Sahodaya 25 Report - Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "container my-3">
        <form method="POST">
<fieldset disabled>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="disabledTextInput" class="form-label">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']?>" name = "name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']?>">
      
      
      <label for="disabledTextInput2" class="form-label my-2">Email</label>
      <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput2" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']?>" name = "email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']?>">
      
      </fieldset>
      <label for="inhouse" class="form-label">Inhouse Training Done In Hours</label>
      <input type="number" id="inhouse" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Here" name = "inhouse" required oninput="showSum()"><br>
      
      <label for="sahodaya" class="form-label">Sahodaya Training Done In Hours</label>
      <input type="number" id="sahodaya" class="form-control" placeholder="JSSC + PSCC (Both)" name = "sahodaya" oninput="showSum()" required><br>
      
      <label for="total" class="form-label">Total Hours Done</label>
      <input type="number" id="total" class="form-control" name = "total" value="0" disabled><br>
      
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
    </div>

        
<script>
    var text1 = document.getElementById("inhouse");
    var text2 = document.getElementById("sahodaya");
    var resultField = document.getElementById("total");
    const showSum = () => {
       resultField.value = Number(text1.value) + Number(text2.value);
    }
    </script>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```